# gem update --system error: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I'm running on windows and I am not able to update my rubygems either from using the command

```
gem update --system
```

or by manually installing the gem. I get the following error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I don't have this issue while installing or updating other gems as far as I can see.

This is the complete output when running with --verbose

http://pasted.co/11325f4e

Comment: write the full error message with trace, please

Comment: Don't use a link to an image that contains information essential to the question. Links rot then break, resulting in nonsensical questions. And, don't use an image for essential information either. Instead, copy/paste the information into the question, formatting it appropriately. That allows us to copy that text and use it for our own searches, and allows the search engines to find it, which helps others locate your question in the future. Please read "[mcve]" and the linked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the ruby gem installer system.

Patch the file `installer.rb`:

Replace:

```
if ruby_executable then
      question << existing
```

With:

```
if ruby_executable then
      question << (existing || 'an unknown executable')
```

Comment: gem update --system  
Updating rubygems-update  
rubygems-update's executable "update_rubygems" conflicts with an unknown executable  
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y  
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.11